# Install extras with conda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

With `pip` we can install subpackages using square brackets. For example with [Apache Airflow](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/installation.html):

```
pip install airflow[all]
```

Is there something similar in `conda` or do I have to use `pip` for packages containing sub-packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It appears that the issue has been raised but not resolved](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2984)

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent of this in `conda`

Closest alternative would be to create your own matapackages that describe list of dependencies. Although this is not exactly what `pip` provides here.

Another option is to use [conda outputs](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#outputs-section) that allows to explicitly specifies packaging steps.

On top of all, please visit this Github page and upvote "Optional groups of dependencies" feature request 
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7502
If "Optional groups of dependencies" for conda are implemented, it would be a direct equivalent for that existing `pip` functionality.

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is still (July 2023) no equivalent to install package extras in conda.

This 2021 conda Enhancement is shown in *Planning* stage: [ENH: More powerful syntax for build variants & optional package-extras](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11053)

To install the `pandas[excel]` extras, I expanded the list, and installed each of them indiviually, a la:

```
mamba --no-banner install --name conda-env -c conda-forge \
      openpyxl \
      pyxlsb \
      xlrd \
      xlsxwriter
```