# What is Conda's equivalent of pip installing optional extra components?

Tags: conda

I have a conda environment into which I'd like to install Jupyter for use with Google BigQuery.

Google provide documentation for using Jupyter with BigQuery at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter and at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter#install_the_client_libraries it is stated that the required dependencies can be installed using:

```
pip install --upgrade 'google-cloud-bigquery[bqstorage,pandas]'
```

However I am not using pip. I am using conda. I already have google-cloud-bigquery installed:

```
# conda list | grep bigquery
google-cloud-bigquery     2.29.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-bigquery-storage-core 2.2.1              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
```

however I do not know how to install the optional extra subcomponents, bqstorage & pandas, that are specified in the pip install command. I know I can issue the same pip install command within my conda environment but I'm wondering if installation of these dependencies can be achieved using only conda.

In summary, how can I achieve the equivalent of `pip install --upgrade 'google-cloud-bigquery[bqstorage,pandas]'` using conda?

Comment: The answer should be generalized to explain the equivalent method in conda to install optional extras. The current answer seems just to list some additional packages manually, which works for the specific use case but does not help for cases where there are many desired extras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOH! I just realised that the article I linked to provides the required conda command

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-bigquery \
  google-cloud-bigquery-storage \
  pandas \
  pyarrow
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shockingly, as of March 2024, conda does not support installation of optional extras in a manner equivalent to pip. Some related discussions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587494/13089441

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7502

https://github.com/fractal-analytics-platform/fractal-tasks-core/issues/611

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2984